# How to show a div block without it disappearing by clicking elsewhere?

Tags: html, css

I have a div block with some text in it with a button that lets it expand to show more text. My issue is that after you expand the text, it will disappear if you click anywhere else. This causes a problem if i add hyperlinks in the expanded text since it then goes away. Is there a way I can make the hidden text stay visible unless the user clicks the red hypertext to expand/collapse it?

```css
.hidden-click {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}

.hidden-click:focus + .hidden-text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Some text here!
  </p>
  <div class="hidden-click" tabindex="1">
    Click to expand
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-text">
    <p>
      more text here!<br>
      But if i add a hyperlink, you cannot click it because the text disappears again! <a href="/">Click meeee</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need javascript for it. This can not be an only HTML/CSS solution, according to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work as expected since you were using `focus`, on the first click, the `hidden-click` will be focused and when you click somewhere else, the focus to the element will be gone, hence the `hidden-block` too

```js
$('.hidden-click').on('click', function() {
  $('.hidden-text').toggleClass('show');
})

$('a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.hidden-click {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}

.hidden-text.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    Some text here!
  </p>
  <div class="hidden-click" tabindex="1">
    Click to expand
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-text">
    <p>
      more text here!<br>
      But if i add a hyperlink, you cannot click it because the text disappears again! <a href="/">Click meeee</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you will be able to achieve the toggling functionality, here I have used 2 functions, one is to capture the click from `hidden-text` and another is to capture from `a`. Since default behaviour of anchor tag is to redirect the screen, we don't want that to happen in our scenario, hence I am preventing it from happening.

Another method you can use is by using checkbox. I will update the answer with that as well here.

```css
.label {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}

.check:checked + .hidden-text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="checkbox">
    Some text here!
  </label>
  <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox' class='check' />
  <div class="hidden-text">
    <p>
      more text here!<br>
      But if i add a hyperlink, you cannot click it because the text disappears again! <a href="/">Click meeee</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this method, I am using a checkbox and based on if the checkbox is checked, I am showing the text, otherwise hiding it.

Comment: In order to retain your `hidden-text`, you should use JavaScript click

Comment: Ah i see. Could you perhaps point me in the right direction to incorporate JS for this?

Comment: Sure, will update in the question in a bit